# How to find out the month from a date when the date format is - day-month-year?

Tags: php

Would you please kindly tell me how to find out the month from a date when the date format is like following?

```
    01/12/2011

  Day-Month-year
```

Thanks :)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615616/how-to-display-a-human-date-to-mysql-date/8615694#8615694

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$thedate = '01/12/2011';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $thedate);

print($date->format('m'));
```

PHP's DateTime object only is available from PHP 5.2 and `createFromFormat()` from PHP 5.2.3.

Alternatively you could fake the timestamp to be the correct format:

```
$thedate = str_replace('/', '-', '01/12/2011');

$date = strtotime($thedate);
print(date('m', $date));
```

Comment: @DanSurfrider yup and it doesn't die in 2038 :)

Comment: Hi, Peehaa.. thanks for your reply. I tried your code but I am getting an error message that says--Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::createfromformat()

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$v = explode('/', $date);
echo $v[1];
```

In PHP 5.4+:

```
$month = explode('/', $date)[1];
```

I also wrote that:

```
$t = strtotime($date);
echo date('m', $t);
```

but **this won't work** since date in format `12/10/2012` is treated as English date so second part `10` is treated as day of month not as month number. You should use

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date)
```

as @PeeHaa suggest.

Comment: strtotime() treats second number as day

Comment: @piotrekkr yup it does in that format. The correct 'format' would be: `01-12-2011`